# File permission Issue

Tags: wordpress, ftp, cpanel

I have modify a file on the theme on the theme editor but I accidentally added ?>. So it is:

```
<?php

...

?>

?>
```

So my issue is that I can't modify the file on ftp. It says that permission denied. I also tried to change the permission to 777 or 750 but I can't change the permission either.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to install plugins at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a solution if you have a ssh access to the server, once you logged as root user, just go to your file and open it with nano or vi for instance :

```
sudo nano yourfile.php
```

Be sure to open it using sudo, and then remove the ?>, press ctrl + X and press Y to save.

Comment: thanks for your response Vincent. Yes, I have access to ssh. Logged in using my whm/root access. But I don't see the wordpress directory. Please refer to this one: http://grab.by/zCxg

Comment: So it depends on how it was installed and what OS is your VPS on, wether you can find it in /var/www or /home/wordpress for a linux based OS. I can't really tell you where it should be on a Windows or else. You can also find it, using 'find /-name wordpress' command if you're on Linux